# WebMatrix FTP publish to a network attached storage (NAS) does not run cshtml

Tags: php, razor, ftp, webmatrix, nas

I built a website on WebMatrix (.cshtml) and I was able to publish via FTP onto our NAS. I have the database up on PHPMyAdmin and MariaDB is installed.

The problem is that even though I can run the website on my browser independently of WebMatrix, it does not run the .cshtml files (just shows the code as text).

I believe it involves Web Deploy on IIS 7.5, but I can't get the sub-menu "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" to show up under Deploy. I tried to follow this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/bernhard_frank/archive/2011/09/01/configure-web-deploy-publishing-missing-in-iis-console.aspx

Where the comments below says to go through Server Manager, but I can't seem to have that either... (Remote Server Administration Tools is up to date).

- Web Deploy 3.5 is installed
- Application pools and WebMatrix set to NET Framework v4.0 Integrated

**Update**
I got my Server Manager up and running, but I'm unable to connect to the NAS.

Comment: Your web server (IIS) needs to be configured to support web deploy. Do you know if that is setup correctly?

Comment: I tried Web Deploy 2.1 and I currently have version 3.5 installed with all the features installed. If you mean on the NAS, I exported the certificates and tried the "connect to a server" option on IIS but it returns a dialog box with 404 error saying it could not connect to the specified computer.

Comment: So what machine is running IIS?  Does it have access to the NAS? The IIS server needs to have access to the files on the NAS.

Comment: My Windows 7 is running the IIS and is mapped to the NAS as a network drive, so it has access to all the files. I can point to files on NAS through localhost, but I can't make another connection to the NAS through IIS.